# How to handle and pass lxml.etree.ParserError in html.fromstring (lxml)

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, html-parsing, lxml

[Sorry if my question is bit naive. I'm new to python and requests.] I've tried many ways, but still couldn't figure a way to pass the lxml.etree.ParserError in html.fromstring.

My code is as follows:

```
    from lxml import html
    import requests
    import time
    import csv
    import pandas as pd

    start = time.time()
    data = {}
    data['webid'] = []
    data['name'] = []
    filename = "xxx"+ str(N) + ".csv"

    for i in range(N):
            url = "http://xxx."+str(i)+".html"
            print(url)
            try:
                    page = requests.get(url,timeout=120)
                    try:
                            tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
                            name = tree.xpath('//h2[starts-with(text(),"Name")]/text()')
                            data['webid'].append(i)
                            data['name'].append(name)

                    except (html.ParseError, ParseError):
                            continue
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                    continue

            dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
            dataframe.to_csv(filename, index=False, sep='|')

    print("took", time.time() - start, "seconds.")
```

The error reads like:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "xxx/xxx.py", line 43, in <module>
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
      File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 876, in fromstring
        doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
      File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 765, in document_fromstring "Document is empty")
    lxml.etree.ParserError: Document is empty
```

I have tried several exceptions, such as except (lxml.etree.ParserError, etree.ParserError, tree.ParserError, html.ParserError), but none of them works, and brings out new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:/Google/Research2017/t/schoolpc/v241.py", line 66, in <module>
    except (lxml.etree.ParserError, ParseError):
NameError: name 'lxml' is not defined
```

May I ask if there are ways to pass the ParserError and continue the loop without raising the error? Thank you very very much!

Much thanks to @BoboDarph, the solution is as follows:

```
from lxml.etree import ParseError
from lxml.etree import ParserError
...except (ParserError, ParseError)
```

"The NameError is caused by how and what you import. In your import statement, you import a specific module of lxml (html) so you cannot call lxml.etree.ParserError or ParseError as they are not imported. Import the specific Exception in another import statement (something like from lxml.etree import ParseError) – BoboDarph "

Comment: The NameError is caused by how and what you import. In your import statement, you import a specific module of lxml (html) so you cannot call lxml.etree.ParserError or ParseError as they are not imported. Import the specific Exception in another import statement (something like from lxml.etree import ParseError)

Comment: @BoboDarph Thank you so much!!! I've amended my code to have "from lxml.etree import ParseError" and "from lxml.etree import ParserError" with except (ParserError, ParseError). I'll update the post as soon as I verify them. Thanks again for your prompt help!

Comment: Another (non-recommended) approach to this would be to try/catch in a very broad Exception and then handle that. I use this for intermediary code until I get a decent idea of the type of exceptions I could be encountering and catch them individually.

Comment: @BoboDarph Good strategy to debug the code in the early stage. Thanks for sharing!